# Enable re-attached mouse/keyboard via ssh?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, usb, keyboard

I had Ubuntu 9.10 x64 Desktop installed on a nettop I have (that I normally run headless), and yesterday I decided to take the plunge and update to 10.04.

So, I plugged in a screen and usb mouse/keyboard, booted up and set to work.

It was 1am, and it was telling me it had 3hrs left to install all the new packages, so I unplugged the screen and usb mouse/keyboard, left the box running, and went to bed.

This evening, I plugged it all back in again to check progress. It's asking if I want to remove obsolete packages. I do, but neither the mouse nor keyboard work!

I can access the box via SSH like I normally do; is there any way I can re-enable the keyboard from there?

I'm reluctant to restart the box (via ssh) mid-way through such a complicated upgrade.

Thanks for any help!

lsusb (with wireless mouse/keyboard receiver unplugged):

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lsusb (with wireless mouse/keyboard receiver attached):

```
Bus 004 Device 005: ID 045e:005f Microsoft Corp. Wireless MultiMedia Keyboard
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: For future reference.  If you are using the box headless then you probably would have been better off running a `do-release-update` within GNU screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure about ubuntu, but you could try a hardware rescan with Kudzu.

Comment: ooh, that looks like it could be ideal. Just tried to install it, but because the upgrade is still paused, I'm blocked from installing anything! Good to know though.

Comment: that's a shame. Have you tried / do you have ports for a ps2 keyboard?

Comment: unfortunately not - it's all usb

Answer (score 1):

did you try to restart udev?

$ sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart

Comment: Just tried that - didn't seem to do anything. Good to know about though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On a desktop install, the keyboard and mouse are run by X.org, so you could try restarting X, which is done on a desktop install by restarting gdm. So

```
sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that when I get home. But will it kill my desktop session?

Answer (score 0):

In the future use screen, so you will be able to detach session and attach via ssh.

@Answer above: If you restart GDM it will crash you X session.